# Grouping terms of linear system of equations

Tags: spacing, equations, alignat

I'm trying to typeset a system of linear equations, and I want to align each of the terms for ease of reading. The best I've managed to achieve is with the alignat environment.

Here's what I've written and what I'm getting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{6}
        &\text{Loop 1: } (\text{Z}_{\text{R}_1} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2})&\text{I}_1(\omega) &- 
        (\text{Z}_{\text{C}_1} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2})&\text{I}_2(\omega) 
        & & &= 1 \\
        &\text{Loop 2: } \qquad -(\text{Z}_{\text{R}_2} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1})&\text{I}_1(\omega) &+ 
        (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1} + \text{Z}_{\text{R}_4} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2} + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1})&\text{I}_2(\omega) 
        &- (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1})&\text{I}_3(\omega) &= 0 \\
        &\text{Loop 3: } & & - 
        (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1})&\text{I}_2(\omega) 
        &- (\text{Z}_{\text{R}_3} + \text{Z}_{\text{C}_2}, + 
        \text{Z}_{\text{L}_1})&\text{I}_3(\omega) &= 0
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

I would greatly appreciate any help getting the terms properly aligned.

Comment: Are the + and - symbols also supposed to be aligned?

Comment: All `\text` commands should be `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % for the first (text) column

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{array}{@{} L @{\quad} rCrCrCl @{}}
Loop 1:& (Z_{R_1} + Z_{C_1} + Z_{R_2})I_1(\omega) 
       &-&(Z_{C_1} + Z_{R_2})I_2(\omega) 
       & &
       &=& 1 \\
Loop 2:&-(Z_{R_2} + Z_{C_1})I_1(\omega) 
       &+&(Z_{L_1}+Z_{R_4}+Z_{R_2}+Z_{C_1})I_2(\omega) 
       &-&(Z_{L_1})I_3(\omega) 
       &=& 0 \\
Loop 3:& 
       & &(Z_{L_1})I_2(\omega) 
       &-&(Z_{R_3} + Z_{C_2} + Z_{L_1})I_3(\omega) 
       &=& 0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this, placing the ‘Loop’s in a `\shortintertext`. It requires geometry to have decent margins (you also can reduce the font size within the equation, with the medium size commands from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{4}
\shortintertext{Loop 1: \vskip -1ex}%
 (\text{Z}_{\text{R}_1} + \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1} + \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2}) & \text{I}_1(\omega) & {}- (\text{Z}_{\text{C}_1} + \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2}) & \text{I}_2(\omega)& & & & = 1 \\
\shortintertext{Loop 2: \vskip -4ex}%
 -(\text{Z}_{\text{R}_2} + \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1}) & \text{I}_1(\omega) & {}+ (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1} + \text{Z}_{\text{R}_4} + \text{Z}_{\text{R}_2} + \text{Z}_{\text{C}_1}) & \text{I}_2(\omega) & {}- (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1}) & \text{I}_3(\omega) & & = 0 \\
\shortintertext{Loop 3: \vskip -4ex} & & - (\text{Z}_{\text{L}_1})&\text{I}_2(\omega) &- (\text{Z}_{\text{R}_3} + \text{Z}_{\text{C}_2}, + \text{Z}_{\text{L}_1})&\text{I}_3(\omega) & & = 0
    \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]